# Exception from IBM ILOG CPLEX: CPLEX Error 5002: 'q1' is not convex.->

Tags: constraint, cplex, nonconvex-programming, multi-objective-optimization

I am currently solving a scheduling optimization problem regarding the fleet management of AGV/AMR. I always get the same error and I don't know where to start to solve it. Here's the code snippet for the objective function and the constraints.

````
// Objective Function

minimize
  sum(m in M, i in T, r in R) (alpha * M_T[m][i] * X[i][m][r] +
                                   beta * Consumption_M_T_R[m][i][r] * X[i][m][r] -
                                   gamma * Y[m][r]);

// Constraints

subject to {

  // Resource Assigned to One Mission

  forall(r in R)
    sum(m in M) Y[m][r] <= 1;

  // All Tasks Performed (Regardless of Resource)

  forall(m in M, i in T)
    sum(r in R) X[i][m][r] == 1;

  // Task Succession within Missions

  forall(m in M, i1 in T, i2 in T : i1 != i2)
    sum(r in R) X[i1][m][r] <= sum(r in R) X[i2][m][r];

  // Mission-Resource Compatibility

  forall(m in M, r in R)
    Y[m][r] <= Compat_M_R[m][r];

  // Segment Compatibility

  forall(m in M, i in T, s1 in S, s2 in S)
    sum(r in R) M_T_Segments[m][i][s1] * M_T_Segments[m][i][s2] * NonExecParalleleSegments[s1][s2] * X[i][m][r] <= 1;

  // Resource Availability

  forall(j in R, r in R : j != r)
    sum(m in M) Y[m][r] <= Z[j];

  // Energy Constraint

  forall(r in R, m in M, i in T)
    W[m][r][i] >= sum(m in M, i in T) Consumption_M_T_R[m][i][r] * X[i][m][r];

  // Calculating Start and End time

  forall(m in M, i in T)
    C[i][m] >= sum(r in R) (St[i][m] * Y[m][r] + M_T[m][i] * X[i][m][r]);
  
  forall(m in M, i in T, s in S)
    sum(s in S) St[i][m] * M_T_Segments[m][i][s] >= sum(s in S, m in M, i in T) C[i][m] * M_T_Segments[m][i][s];
}
```
````

Answer (score 0):

You did not identify the variables in your model. Presumably X is a variable. If either M_T or Consumption_M_T_R is a variable, then your objective function is a nonconvex quadratic function. If any of the other matrices in the code snippet are variables, then you may have nonconvex quadratic functions in the constraints as well.

Comment: // Decision Variables
dvar boolean X[T][M][R]; // Binary variable indicating if task i of mission m is performed by resource r
dvar boolean Y[M][R]; // Binary variable indicating if resource r is assigned to mission m
dvar boolean Z[R]; // Binary variable indicating if resource r is occupied and assigned to a mission
dvar float St[T][M]; // Start time of task i of mission m
dvar float C[T][M]; // End time of task i of mission m
dvar float W[M][R][T]; // Energy required to perform task i of mission m on resource r

Comment: M_T and Consumption_M_T_R are input data in fact.

Comment: So the problem is apparently your next to last constraint, where you multiply St and Y.